# View display issue with iPad Mini, iOS8

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ipad, swift

I was testing my app on the iPad mini iOS8. I found a strange thing. If I put a `contentView` inside a `scrollView`, and the `scrollView` takes the full space of `self.view`, then the `contentView` will only show up on the top-left of the screen, taking up about 1/4 of the portrait screen size. The `contentView` looks like the exact the same size as what it looks like on iPhone.(Shouldn't it look bigger on iPad?). The deployment target is set to be iOS8 and iPhone only.

When I test on a iPad2 with iOS7, everything looks the way it should be. No idea what's going wrong with iPad mini and iOS8.

Comment: We can't read minds, only code.

Comment: What are your autolayout constraints? Are you sure you have the content view's width and height set to match the container size?

Comment: We have to include your code so that we can help you better

Answer (score 0):

Your answer lies at the **Autolayout Constraints** . You haven't set them for the container you added. To run your app on any iOS device it is mandatory that you select the **whANY hANY** from the Size Class